# SQL getting similar values

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++
NAME   |PRODUCT
Bob    |Apple
Bob    |Orange
Bob    |Banana
Amy    |Apple
Amy    |Watermelon
Chris  |Orange
++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to output a table that looks like this;

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
NAME | PRODUCTS_BOUGHT | PPL_BUYING_SAME_PRODUCTS
Bob  | 3               | 2
Amy  | 2               | 1
Chris| 1               | 1
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I do that?
I know I can create the columns as tempfields but how do I write the code to get those values?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
select p.name, count(distinct p.product) as numproducts,
       count(distinct p2.name) as numpeople
from products p left join
     products p2
     on p.product = p2.product and p.name <> p2.name
group by p.name;
```

This seems like a rather expensive query.  Nothing simpler comes to mind, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
with c as (select count(a.name) cnt ,a.name from test a where exists(select 1 from test b where a.product =b.product and a.name<>b.name) 
group by a.name)
SELECT A.NAME, COUNT(A.name) products_bought, cnt

ppl_buying_same_product FROM TEST A JOIN c on(a.name = c.name)
group by A.name,cnt;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff did a better job, as usual.

Comment: imo, It isn't any reflection on our abilities... but we learn a lot. SO is a better place because of people like this who are willing to share their skills :)